# How to read header and footer lines with RTFEditorKit

Tags: java, swing, rtf

does somebody know how to get the header / footer of a RTF file ?
I tried something like this (using the RTfEditorKit):

```
    RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();

    DefaultStyledDocument docIn = (DefaultStyledDocument) rtf.createDefaultDocument();

    try {

        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("zf_static_follow.out.rtf");
        rtf.read(fi, docIn, 0);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    docIn.getProperty("header");//  <-- null
    System.out.println(docIn.getProperty("headerf")); //   <--null
    System.out.println(docIn.getProperty("headerl")); //   <--null
    System.out.println(docIn.getProperty("headerr")); //   <--null
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
br 
Markus

Comment: did you manage to get the header from a RTF? The answer below does not clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `public Dictionary<Object,Object> getDocumentProperties()` method of `AbstractDocument` and see all existing properties of the `Document`.

Comment: this I did, but the header and footer doesn't appeare. I tried the advanced RTFEditorKit, and I've got what I'm looking for. I just want to be sure I did it right.

Comment: The standard RTFEditorKit does not support headers and footers, images, tables etc.

Comment: Ok. So I will try the advanced RTFEditorKit. Thanx Stanislav